# Can't install Elementary OS on NVMe

Tags: system-installation, release-hera, hardware

I have Acer laptop with 2 drives - hdd & nvme. Elementary OS installer can see only hdd (the same situation is while running EOs from flash drive - I can see only hdd). There is no ahci swithchers in bios. I tried to run the command "nvme_load=YES" as Dell website recommended for ubuntu, but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you give us more details about your laptop? Brand? model? CPU?

Comment: Also, are you using the newest ISO available from Elmementary's site?

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the HDD on my computer before I could install Elementary OS onto the NVME drive.  If you can't remove the HDD easily look in the BIOS to see if there is an option to turn of the particular SATA port your HDD is attached to.